# MacTeX 2014 installation failed - no software found to install

Tags: installing, mactex

I'm having trouble installing MacTeX 2014 after I've uninstalled 2013 on my Mac. Whenever I try to install, I get the following error clicking *Install*.

[image: screenshot]

I've tried to only install TeXLive-2014 and skip GhostScript and the GUI application, but that didn't help

[image: screenshot]

**the same also happens if I try to only install either GhostScript or the GUI Applications.**

I also tried downloading the MacTeX version from the Torrent, but I'm getting the same result. The exact version I'm trying is mactex-20140525.pkg

Comment: Why did you uninstall MacTeX 2013? Not that doing so should cause problems. I'm just curious. Is there a checksum available which you can use to verify the download? Does MacTeX still include the software in the installer? Or does it now use the net install method? If the latter, is your internet connection good?

Comment: See http://www.tug.org/mactex/faq/index.html#qm01. Verify your download and check if any of the other suggestions apply.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds really odd, but for some reason the MacTeX file can be corrupted through non-Safari browsers. Try downloading the file again but this time in the Safari browser.

I've run into this problem before, and just ran into it again now. However, this fix has now worked for me twice on two different computers and at two different times.

Comment: This is a rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, what do you mean? I think this is the solution to the problem...

Comment: @DavidDiez Here, many people have used Chrome or Firefox to download and install MacTeX without any problems...

Comment: @PaulGaborit I've found the zip file corruption to be a sporadic problem... it's seemed to fix it twice for me when I have had issues in 2010 (IIRC) and 2014. This solution had been reported in another forum when I had run into this issue the first time around. I don't have an explanation about why this fix would work, and yeah, I was skeptical as hell the first time I tried it. I'm still not 100% sure it is a true fix. But rather than not suggest what has worked for me, I figured I'd toss out a possible solution for those encountering the exact same problem.

Comment: @DavidDiez Did you actually try **all** browsers other than Safari?

Comment: @PaulGaborit I think I've clearly indicated that my experiences are anecdotal and are not rigorous. But I'd feel like a jerk if I didn't try to help others who are running into the same obscure problem I encountered. Sadly, I'm starting to regret that decision...

Comment: I hit this error using a copy of Mactex 2016 I downloaded with Chrome 58. Redownloading with Safari solved the problem.